# Trouble SSH Tunneling to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to get from my local machine to a remote vendor's website that is locked down by IP (our corporate servers are allowed access). I am doing this by tunneling from a server that can access the API without issues, however, when I setup the SSH tunnel and go to a URL on the vendor website, I get a 404 Not Found error.  Here is what I'm using:

```
ssh -f -N user@example.com -L 7777:vendorhostexample.com:80
```

Everything indicates that the tunnel is setup correctly, but if I try a URL such as 'http://localhost:7777/foobar', I get the 404 error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you are sending the http header "Location: localhost" which means if the destination webserver is using virtualhosts, it will try to lookup for website "localhost" and not for website "vendorhostexample.com"

One way is as Ryan pointed out to modify your hosts file and tell your machine that vendorhostexample.com it's on 127.0.0.1, that way when you type it in your browser you will go through the tunnel with the right "Host:" http header set.

Another way it's installing an extension for your browser to change the Host header like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) for firefox.

Comment: Finally got around to looking at this... it works if I change the Host header, but I can't get it work by just pointing the vendor URL to my localhost - any idea why this isn't working? I'm not always going through a browser and don't want to change the Host in my code if not necessary.

Comment: If you add on your hosts file (/etc/hosts on linux) a line telling your machine that vendorhostexample it's on 127.0.0.1, you won't need to set the host header. The line will look like this: `127.0.0.1 vendorhostexample.com www.vendorhostexample.com`

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else has already mentioned the issue with the domain name matching the wrong virtual host. Another solution can be to use dynamic tunnels.

If you open a connection with the `-D 8080` flag, SSH will open a dynamic tunnel, and expose a SOCKS proxy on port 8080. If you then set your browser (or application of your choice) up to use a SOCKS proxy on localhost:8080, you can tunnel all of your traffic out to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your local hosts(/etc/hosts for linux) file, and add a line like:

```
127.0.0.1 vendorhostexample.com
```

and try again.

Comment: I'm still getting a 404 after trying this - does the port have to be 80 on both sides of the tunnel for this method to work?

Answer (score -1):

You're breaking HTTP with this. Your browser is sending the hostname `localhost` in the HTTP headers, which means you're request the `localhost` website of the vendor's site. They almost certainly aren't hosing a `localhost` site on their server, so you get the 404.

You cannot tunnel HTTP in the way you are. You need to set up a proper HTTP proxy on your company servers.

Comment: What's best way to setup the Http proxy?

Comment: You don't need to setup an http proxy for this, there are many ways to achieve it without one. From changing localhost as @raynix pointed out up to add a browser extension to replace "Host:" header of the request.