# SSH forward port to local host name

Tags: nginx, ssh, proxy, vagrant, portforwarding

I have next setup:

- Local host - my work PC
- Project VM - Vagrant box with project files, runned on my work PC
- Remote host - remote PC, from which I need to access hosts on Project VM

Project VM setup (/etc/hosts on Local host):

```
192.168.100.102 host1.vm.private
192.168.100.102 sub1.host1.vm.private
192.168.100.102 sub2.host1.vm.private
```

"host1" subdomains resolved by application router and served by nginx (config for "host1.vm.private" on Project VM):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.+\.)?host1\.vm\.private$;
    ...
}
```

I need to make "sub(1|2|N).host1.vm.private" reachable from remote host. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i found the solution: [Trouble SSH Tunneling to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845595/trouble-ssh-tunneling-to-remote-server)

The main issue is that invalid HTTP header was sent and nginx cant resolve a virtual host.

1. Run on **local** PC `ssh -R 8888:192.168.100.102:80 <remote_pc_credentionals>`. Or, run "inversed" command with ssh `-L` flag on remote PC.
2. Add "sub1.host1.vm.private" to `/etc/hosts` on **remote** PC: `127.0.0.1 sub1.host1.vm.private`

**OR**

3. Send "Host" header with each request: `curl -H "Host: sub1.host1.vm.private" "http://localhost:8888/some/path"`